# ProjectReference assemblies not copied to startup project's output dir when using msbuild command line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build, msbuild, build-process

In Visual Studio 2012, I have a solution with multiple projects in it.

```
Solution S
  - Project A (startup project) (references project B)
  - Project B
```

My main project (Project A) has a project reference to another of my projects (Project B).

My main project compiles to C:\MAIN_BIN and my other project compiles to HisProjectFolder/Bin.

```
Project A builds to: C:\MAIN_BIN
Project B builds to: C:\SolutionS\ProjectB\Bin
```

The reference to Project B on Project A is set as `Copy Local = True`. In the csproj file, the property `<Private>True</Private>` is set for the project reference to Project B.

When I Build my solution using Visual Studio 2012, ProjectB.dll is compiled to his bin folder, and then copied into C:\MAIN_BIN.

When I build using msbuild from the command line, ProjectB.dll is compiled to his bin folder, and **never** copied to C:\MAIN_BIN.

How can I make it so msbuild behaves the same way as Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `OutDir` property explicitly:

```
msbuild s.sln /p:OutDir=C:\MAIN_BIN\ /t:Rebuild
```

Comment: That did not fix the problem.